# Multiple Cartesian Joins pySpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm getting memory errors when doing multiple cartesian joins even though it's really small data sets. Can anyone explain why this would occur?

```
In [1]: foo = sc.records([{'foo': 123}, {'foo': 321}])
In [2]: bar = sc.records([{'bar': 123}, {'bar': 321}])
In [3]: baz = sc.records([{'baz': 123}, {'baz': 321}])
In [4]: qux = foo.cartesian(bar)\
   ...:          .map(lambda (x,y): x.merge(y))\
   ...:          .cartesian(baz)\
   ...:          .map(lambda (x,y): x.merge(y))
In [5]: qux.collect()

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining my own cartesianJoin function

```
def cartesianJoin(self, other):
    return self.map(lambda rec: (0, rec)).join(other.map(lambda rec: (0, rec))).map(lambda (key, (x, y)): x.merge(y))
end
```